# How can I manage a variable count of calls to an async service

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Given:**

```
[1,2,3,4,5] variable array of numbers
```

I want to call an asynchronous method for each number in the array. What are some ways to manage this? The return type of the async method is JSON.

What I'm expecting is a new JSON array with the results from the calls

```
[{id:1,name:"name1"},
{id:2,name:"name2"},
{id:3,name:"name3"},
{id:4,name:"name4"},
{id:5,name:"name5"}]
```

**Latest results**

**app.js**

```
( () => {
    const result =  adapterContext.get([1, 2, 3]);
    console.log(result);
})();
```

**service.js**

```
exports.get = list => {
    Promise.all(list.map(promise-method-call))
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("response", response);
            return response;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("oops ", error);
        });
};
```

**results**

> Why is the console.log(result) undefined?

```
undefined  
response [ '{"hello":1}', '{"hello":2}', '{"hello":3}' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. First, you need to return the `Promise.all` call from your service:

```
exports.get = list => {
  // Make sure to return the promise!
  return Promise.all(list.map(promise-method-call))
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("response", response);
      return response;
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("oops ", error);
    });
};
```

---

Then, inside your app need to wait for the `get` method to finish. There are two ways to do this:

#### Old school `.then` chaining:

```
(() => {
  const result =  adapterContext.get([1, 2, 3]).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
})();
```

#### Cool kids async/await

```
(async () => {
  const result = await adapterContext.get([1, 2, 3]);
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `Promise.all`. Without knowing the specifics of your method or the api I can't say for sure, but you might want something like `const results = await Promise.all(array.map(someMethod))`.

Answer (score 1):

Well Here is something that could help, run the snippet and see what the outcome is like.

```js
var getAsyncObjectWithList = function(idList) {
  const promiseHandler = function(resolve, reject) {

      // fake async call, like http call
      setTimeout(function() {
        // fake conditional statement
        // for error cases
        if (!idList) { 
          reject("no ids specified");
          return;
        }

        // do actual processing here
        var newList = idList.map(function(id) {
          return { id: id, name: "name: "+id }
        });
        // return result by resolving list
        resolve(newList);
      },  3000)
  }

  return new Promise(promiseHandler);
}

// success case
getAsyncObjectWithList([1,2,3,4]).then(function(response) {
    console.log("response", response);
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("oops ", error);
});

// error case
getAsyncObjectWithList().catch(function(error){
    console.log("oops ", error);
});


var getAsyncObjectWithId = function(id) {
  const promiseHandler = function(resolve, reject) {
      // fake async call, like http call
      setTimeout(function() {
          // fake conditional statement
          // for error cases
          if (!id) {
            reject("no id specified");
            return;
          }

          // do actual processing here
          var newObj = { id: id, name: "name: "+id };

          // return result by resolving object
          resolve(newObj);
      }, 3000);
  }

  return new Promise(promiseHandler);
}

// success case
Promise.all([1,2,4,5].map(getAsyncObjectWithId))
.then(function(response) {
    console.log("response", response);
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("oops ", error);
});

// error case
getAsyncObjectWithId().catch(function(error){
    console.log("oops ", error);
});
```

Comment: ```// do actual processing here
      var newObj = { id: id, name: "name: "+id };```

Comment: what if the above snippet is an asynchronous service, what would that line look like?

Comment: Can you have it call the following test service
 ```
var testServiceAsync = (x) => {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (x === 1)
                resolve('hey2');
            else
                reject(new Error('Error has occurred.'));
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Comment: if it asynchronous it can be put in that blcok, "// do actual processing here", it will work, as long as the service is not a promise, for which the solution above is pointless, as you would have just a promise calling into another promise.

Comment: I will add the snippet, so you would see what a long processing unit would look like

Comment: the service is a promise

Comment: If it is a promise then just use the "then" and "catch" methods of the returned promise, if you want to get the result as a list, then do a (Promise.all) on the list of operations, just like i did above.

Comment: ```console.log("response", response);``` So this line prints what looks to be the desired results  ```response [ '{"hello":1}', '{"hello":2}', '{"hello":3}' ]```  however, if I try to ```return response``` it's undefiined?